# Coerce result of `eval` division by zero to zero

Tags: javascript, math

I have a requirement where I need to manage javascript 'eval' in such a way that if any calculation's result is infinity, I want it to turn it 0.

```
var x = 10
var y = 20
var a = eval(x * y / 0 + 5)
```

For above calculation ideally result should be infinity + 5 that is infinity but I want infinity + 5 should be 0 + 5 = 5.

I know 0/0 is not infinity, but this is just a requirement

Comment: Since when should division by zero equal zero?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: 0 divide by 0 is undefined in maths, not infinity not zero

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, at any point the expression becomes infinity, set it to 0 and keep evaluating?

```js
function EVAL(exp) {
  exp.replace(/ /, ''); // Remove whitespace
  exps = exp.split(/(?=[+\-*/])/); // Split by operators
  var result = exps[0];
  for (var x = 1; x < exps.length; x++) {
    result = eval(result + exps[x]);
    if (!isFinite(result)) result = 0;
  }
  return result;
}

alert(EVAL("10+3/0+5"));
```

Comment: suppose var tmp=eval(x * y / 0 + 5) in this case it would become infinity where as per my requirement it should be 5. it has 3 evaluations that are x*y, (X*y)/0 and (x*y/0)+5.

Comment: @user3133994 You're welcome, it was a bit of an unusual request but I'm glad I was able to help!  Please mark a correct answer if your question is resolved.

Comment: sure, let m try in my code. but still many thanks i will think in that way.

Comment: My reputation is not 15 so cant mark it as right answer :( but its working :) thanks

Comment: @user3133994: You can always accept answers to your own question, even if your rep is 1. Just click the checkmark next to the answer. However, note that the above is **extremely limited**. (Doesn't mean it's not helpful as a starting point.) It doesn't handle `()`, for instance, nor does it handle operator precedence correctly. To do that, you'd need something *significantly* more complicated, involving something called an *expression parser*.

Comment: I need to customize this solution as its not wholely correct

Comment: Like he said, it's a start. Not a code writing service. Completely parsing an expression would be way too long for an answer, but the general idea is there.

Answer (score 0):

> For above calculation ideally result should be infinity + 5

`Infinity + 5` **is** `Infinity`. Try just `Infinity + 5` in the console.

> ...should be 0 + 5 = 5...

I have no idea what you're trying to say there, but the way your expression is evaluated is like this:

```
((x * y) / 0) + 5
```

There's no point where you would have `0 + 5`, the addition happens at the end, when the other operations have completed.

---

Note: You don't need or want `eval` here at all. Simply:

```
var x = 10;
var y = 20;
var a = x * y / 0 + 5;
```

Comment: Its my client's requirement to simply replace infinity result by 0. as in the above calculation 10*20/0=infinity and infinity + 5 = infinity. if you evaluate above code with javascript eval function, it will simply give result as infinity. I want result as infinity + 5=0+5=5

Comment: @user3133994: If your client wants you to replace `Infinity` with `0`, you'll have to do that explicitly. (E.g.: `if (!isFinite(result)) { result = 0; } result += 5;`) It's completely contrary to all standard rules of math.

Comment: You are not getting my point. I am not saying about whole evaluation, I am asking about a part of it. May be you are interpreting it wrong T. J. Crowder. And I know its wrong mathematics, but still we want that

Comment: X / 0 equals infinity, except when x=0 which is undefined

Comment: @user3133994: I'm getting your point. If, at any stage in the calculation, you want to convert `Infinity` to `0`, you must do that **on purpose, yourself**. Whether it's an intermediate result that you want to convert or a final result is completely irrelevant; **you** have to do it, because it's non-standard math, so JavaScript won't do it for you.

Comment: yes I know it wont allow, thats why posted the question, to have some regular expression sort of things, but anyways i got the answer, Thanks for your comments T.J..Crowder :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about your requirement. To turn infinity to zero use 'if statements'
Try this code:

```
var x = 10;
var y = 20;
var a = x * y;
//checks if a is zero or not 
if(a==0)
{
//if a is zero assign value of c is equal to 5 to avoid infinity problem 
c=5;
}
else
{
c=b/0+5;
}
```

Comment: i dont wanna check whole result, i just wanna ceck if any calculation within the evaluation causing infinity, i want it as 0. please see the example i have given

Comment: you need to write a custom function that replaces 'eval' to solve this problem